# Random Geometric Graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, random

I'm trying to implement an application which uses random geometric graphs in Mathematica, but it seems Mathematica lacks the functionality. I need the following functionalities:

1. Generate a set of uniformly distributed vertices on $[0,1]^2$ with certain properties ([this really helps](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/efficient-way-to-generate-random-points-with-a-predefined-lower-bound-on-their-p))
2. Add an edge in between the vertices that are closer than a given radius $d$
3. Display the graph (this is not like a regular graph display since the location of each vertex is important)
4. Generate some random source-destination pairs and find the shortest path between them
5. Highlight the path on the displayed graph.

Note that, Mathematica has all of the required functionality for non-geometric graphs. However, when it comes to the geo-graphs, the functionality is quite useless.
Here is the code I already have:

```
Module[
 {nOld, kOld, v, edges},
 nOld = -1;
 kOld = -1;
 Manipulate[
  If[
   n != nOld,
   v = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}];
   nOld = n
   ];

  edges = 
   Select[Flatten[Table[{a, b}, {a, v}, {b, v}], 
     1], (#[[1, 1]] > #[[2, 1]] && 
       EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] < d) &];

  Graphics[
   {Red, Point[v],
    Blue, Thin, Line /@ edges
    }
   ]
  ,
  {n, 10, 100, 10},
  {d, 0, 1}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It generates and shows the random graph. But generating and highlighting the shortest paths are not so simple since I don't have any data-structure to keep the graph. What is the best way to implement a geo-graph in Mathematica? `Sparse matrices` or `` System`Graph `` or `` Combinatorica`Graph ``? Can I use some of the built-in graph functions of Mathematica to implement geo-graphs?

Comment: Would a Delaunay triangulation of a random set of points on the plane help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Slight modification of your code allows using `Graph` and all options that come with it:

```
 Module[{nOld, kOld, v, vertices, edges}, nOld = -1; kOld = -1;
 Manipulate[If[n != nOld, v = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}];
 nOld = n]; vertices = Range@n;
 edges =   Select[Flatten[Table[{a, b}, {a, v}, {b, v}], 1],
   (#[[1, 1]] > #[[2, 1]] &&  EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] < d) &];
 edgelst = Map[Rule[First@First@Position[v, #[[1]]], 
     First@First@Position[v, #[[2]]]] &, edges];
 Graph[vertices, edgelst, VertexCoordinates -> v, 
    DirectedEdges -> False], {n, 10, 100, 10}, {d, 0, 1}]]
```

screenshot:

[image]

EDIT: Adding `RandomSample`, `HighlightGraph` and `ShortestPath`:

```
Module[{nOld, kOld, v, vertices, edges, edgelst}, nOld = -1;  kOld = -1;
Manipulate[If[n != nOld, v = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}]; 
  vertices = Range@n; {source, destination} = RandomSample[vertices, 2];
   nOld = n];
edges = Select[Flatten[Table[{a, b}, {a, v}, {b, v}], 1], 
    (#[[1, 1]] > #[[2, 1]] && EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] < d) &];
edgelst =  Map[Rule[First@First@Position[v, #[[1]]], 
  First@First@Position[v, #[[2]]]] &, edges];
gr = Graph[vertices, edgelst, VertexCoordinates -> v,  DirectedEdges -> False]; 
HighlightGraph[gr, 
  PathGraph[FindShortestPath[gr, vrtx1, vrtx2]]], 
{n, 10, 100, 10}, {d, 0, 1}, Delimiter,  Style["shortestPath", "Subsection"], 
{{vrtx1, source, "fromVertex"}, vertices}, 
{{vrtx2, destination, "toVertex"}, vertices}]]
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: To take the lengths of the edges into account when calculating the shortest path you could set the option `EdgeWeight -> weights` in `gr` where `weights` is a list of the lengths of the edges.

Comment: Thank you @Heike. Good point. I will add the `Edgeweight` option.

Comment: You need to be careful when adding `EdgeWeight`. It seems that there is a bug which causes Mathematica to crash when evaluating `FindShortestPath[gr, a, b]` for a weighted graph `gr` in the case that there is no path between `a` and `b`. To be on the safe side you could check whether `GraphDistance[gr, vrtx1, vrtx2] < Infinity` first before trying to find the shortest path.

Comment: How can I highlight multiple paths with different styles?

Comment: Thank you again @Heike, I was struggling with that crash problem for a while now.

Comment: @Mohsen you can use `Style` for that, e.g. `HighlightGraph[CompleteGraph[6], {Style[PathGraph[{1, 2, 3, 4}], Green], Style[PathGraph[{2, 6, 3}], {Red, Dashed}]}]`

Comment: @Mohsen, `FindShortestPath` returns a single path; for multiple shortest paths pls see the answers to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4128/125). Once you find the shortest paths, highlighting them with different styles is easy: For example, you can try something like: `HighlightGraph[PetersenGraph[5,  2], {Style[PathGraph[FindShortestPath[PetersenGraph[5, 2], 10, 1]],{Thick, Purple}], Style[PathGraph[FindShortestPath[PetersenGraph[5, 2], 2, 9]], Directive[Thick, Cyan]]}]`.

Comment: @Heike and kguler: Thanks for your answers. I'd appreciate your time if you also post your reply here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5661/highlightgraph-with-different-styles - The question on the other page asks for directed paths as well.

Comment: @kglr Hi, first off, wonderful answer! If I may ask two tiny questions: (i) Is it possible to read in a graph and just do the visualisation with your approach? (ii) In your approach, can we additionally restrict that there are no overlapping vertex positions? Many thanks.

Comment: @user929304, thank you for the kind words. For part (i) you can do something like: `manipulateGraph =  Manipulate[ vertices = VertexList[#]; {source, destination} =  RandomSample[vertices, 2];
    HighlightGraph[#, PathGraph[FindShortestPath[#, vrtx1, vrtx2]]], 
    Style["shortestPath", 
     "Subsection"], {{vrtx1, source, "fromVertex"}, 
     vertices}, {{vrtx2, destination, "toVertex"}, vertices}] &;
g = RandomGraph[{20, 40}];
manipulateGraph[g]` For (ii) you can remove the option `VertexCoordinates` and use `GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"` or any other built-in layout.

Comment: @kglr Brilliant, thanks! I'll work with this graph option.This reminds me of something I've been struggling with: in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159484/creating-random-configurations-of-spherocylinders-or-cylinders) Henrik shows a way of filling a box with capsules randomly placed without overlap. I wonder, are there simple ways to insert the capsules in a regular grid structure? This increases (i think) the chance of fitting even more capsules into the box, because when randomized position and orientation, the box quickly jams and no more capsules can be added.

Answer (score 7):

In the latest version of *Mathematica*, [SpatialGraphDistribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SpatialGraphDistribution.html) can be use to generate random geometric graphs:

```
n = 30; d = 0.5;
g = RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[n, d]];
{source, target} = RandomInteger[{1, n}, 2];
path = FindShortestPath[g, source, target];
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[path]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your edges to the indices:

```
edges = Select[Flatten[Table[{a, b}, {a, n}, {b, a + 1, n}], 1],
    (EuclideanDistance[v[[#[[1]]]], v[[#[[2]]]]] < d) &];
```

And then tell the `Graph` where to locate the vertices:

```
g = Graph[Range[n], edges, VertexCoordinates -> v];
```

A shortest path display can be taken straight from the help:

```
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[FindShortestPath[g,
   RandomInteger[{1, n}], RandomInteger[{1, n}]]]]
```