# HighlightGraph with style

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In this picture you see a graph. The shortest path between vertex 5 and vertex 3 is highlighted in red. Instead I want blue highlighted edges of thickness 10.

```
HighlightGraph[WheelGraph[6, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Black,AbsoluteThickness[10]]],
 PathGraph@FindShortestPath[WheelGraph[6], 5, 3], 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> {"Red", AbsoluteThickness[10]}]
```

[image: a]

I tried this. The thickness went to 10, but why is the highlighted path not blue?

```
HighlightGraph[WheelGraph[6, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[10]],
  VertexSize -> 0], PathGraph@FindShortestPath[WheelGraph[6], 5, 3],
  GraphHighlightStyle -> {"Blue", AbsoluteThickness[10]}]
```

[image: b]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also `Style` sub-graphs directly (see [@Heike's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5661/125) to a related question)

```
 HighlightGraph[WheelGraph[6, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[10]]], 
   Style[PathGraph[FindShortestPath[WheelGraph[6], 5, 3]],
          {{Blue,  AbsoluteThickness[10]}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It seems that `GraphHighlightStyle` takes only built-in options:

```
GraphElementData["GraphHighlightStyle"]
```

> {Automatic, "Dashed", "Dotted", "Thick", "VertexConcaveDiamond", 
>   "VertexDiamond", "VertexTriangle", "DehighlightFade", 
>   "DehighlightGray", "DehighlightHide"}

To achieve what you're looking for you can wrap up a solution customizing the `EdgeStyle`:

```
WheelGraph[6, 
 EdgeStyle -> 
  Flatten@{(# -> {Blue, AbsoluteThickness[10]} & /@ 
      EdgeList[
       PathGraph@FindShortestPath[WheelGraph[6], 5, 3]]), {Directive[
      Black, AbsoluteThickness[10]]}}, VertexSize -> 0]
```

[image]