# How to use the built-in function GraphElementData

Tags: function-construction, built-in-symbols

Very surprise to me.I found this is a built-in function but it is undocumented.Such as [this answer's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83768/21532) `"CurvedArc"` and `"Curvature"`,[this answer's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5662/21532) `"EdgeShapeFunction"`,[this answer's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22371/21532) `"GraphHighlightStyle"` and so on.I confuse these friend how to find these parameter.Anyone can give a method to find those parameters and other?

Comment: Undocumented options / functions have been discussed extensively on this site, e.g. [What are some useful, undocumented Mathematica functions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/27951), and [Is using undocumented functionality a Bad Idea™?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5940/27951). A search for "undocumented" in this site will return many such examples. There are no obvious methods to find undocumented functionality, but hunting for them is certainly fun!

Comment: @MarcoB I'm not sure if we can call it undocumented.  It is mentioned in many documentation pages, but it doesn't have its own page or usage message!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some digging, I found this symbol is related to the undocumented `` GraphComputation`GraphElementDataDump`RawNetworkGraphData ``.You can find the usages you mentioned and much more by typing the code:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[GraphComputation`GraphElementDataDump`RawNetworkGraphData]
```

Here is preview of a portion of definitions, you can follow the links inside to trace function calls.
[image]

FYI, the process of my digging is actually simple, just turn on the undocumented option: `TraceInternal->True` in `Trace` or `TracePrint`, and you can find out more about its evaluation.

### If MMA returns an empty notebook

You have to evaluate `GraphElementData["EdgeShapeFunction"]` first, or the definitions won't load and the page will be blank.

### If `PrintDefinitions` says too many definitions

This will happen in version before 10.4. In this case you can use `Information`.

Comment: @yode thanks for your markdown suggestion, I didn't know it before.

Comment: You are welcome,be my guest.:)

Comment: BTW, what's your Mathematica version?

Comment: @ShutaoTANG 10.4.1, but I can roughly guess the problem, see my update.

Comment: @happyfish Thanks, in **V10.3.1**, ``PrintDefinitions[GraphComputation`GraphElementDataDump`RawNetworkGraphData]`` return a **empty** notebook

Comment: @ShutaoTANG this will work: ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
GraphElementData["EdgeShapeFunction"];
?? GraphComputation`GraphElementDataDump`RawNetworkGraphData``