# Variance of geodesic path length in a random geometric graph

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to calculate the variance of the passage time over various distances in a random geometric graph.

I am able to quickly generate a random geometric graph with e.g. `SpatialGraphDistribution`. I then set the `EdgeWeights` as the respective Euclidean length...

```
r0 = 0.2;    
density = 100;
Ngraphs = 100;
n = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[density], Ngraphs];
ed[rg_] := 
  EuclideanDistance @@@ 
   Map[PropertyValue[{rg, #}, VertexCoordinates] &, EdgeList[rg], {2}];
graph6 = Table[
    RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[n[[k]], r0]], {k, 1, 
     Ngraphs}]; // AbsoluteTiming
graph6 = SetProperty[#, EdgeWeight -> ed[#]] & /@ 
    graph6; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It is a bit slow setting the weights! But, for now...

Define the passage time $T(x,y)$ to be the Euclidean length of a shortest path between vertices $x$ and $y$.

I need to plot the variance of the passage time $\text{Var}\left(T(x,y)\right)$ against $||x-y||$, which shows how this variance changes as the path spans an increasing distance. The conjecture I have is that this variance converges to a positive constant as $||x-y|| \to \infty$. The difficulty is I can't fix two vertices at $||x-y||$ in the graph using this `SpatialGraphDistribution` method. So I sample many pairs, and for each record 1) their Euclidean separation, and 2) the passage time $T$ along the geodesic running between them.

Is there a way I can then quickly take these samples of the passage time for e.g. uniformly random pairs, say 5% of all pairs in a graph, and then produce a plot of $T(||x-y||)$ vs $||x-y||$?

At the moment I am binning the distances of random pairs, but it is inelegant.

Comment: I can also generate the graphs without using `SpatialGraphDistribution`, thanks to excellent help in another question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166732/random-geometric-graphs-but-fast. For now I am more concerned with this problem of efficiently sampling the passage time. However, the two questions are entwined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this function approximate what you are looking for?

```
distanceplot[G_Graph] := Module[{pts, A, B},
  pts = PropertyValue[G, VertexCoordinates];
  A = Flatten[
    DeleteCases[UpperTriangularize[GraphDistanceMatrix[G], 1], 
     0., {2}]];
  B = Flatten[
    DeleteCases[UpperTriangularize[DistanceMatrix[pts, pts], 1], 
     0., {2}]];
  ListPlot[Transpose[{B, A}], AxesLabel -> {"EuclideanDistance", "GraphDistanceMatrix"}]
  ]

distanceplot[graph6[[1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps I just look at the variance of the samples on vertical strips, and then plot against the respective strips Euclidean distance?

Comment: Now it's graph distance (with respect to the Euclidean edge lengths) vs. Euclidean distance (chord distance).

Comment: That is very fast code. Looks like I can use this, and plot $\text{Var}(T)$for almost continuous values of $||x-y||$.

Comment: Good to hear that this may help you!

Comment: Is it possible to take the list of pairs `Transpose[{B,A}]`, and sort the list into bins corresponding to a short range of Euclidean distance? Then I can quickly see which graph distances correspond to e.g. Euc. distances about equal to $d$. But it looks relatively straightforward.

Comment: Try `SortBy[Transpose[{B,A}],First]` for sorting. Binning can maybe done with the tree-argument variant of `BinLists`.

Comment: OK nice, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!