# Toroidal metric in a random geometric graph

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I have some code I've been using to generate some [random geometric graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_geometric_graph) as fast as possible.

The boundary conditions on the rectangular domain I am using sometimes interferes with a clean measurement of some sensitive exponents.

Can I modify the distance metric between the random points from the Euclidean to the *toroidal*, which simply implies I have a rectangle with periodic boundary conditions?

I'm able to write out only a simple function which takes two positions and gives their toroidal distance (given this is a rectangle $[0,w] \times [0,h]$), but I may need something a bit more efficient.

For example, [this code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166732/random-geometric-graphs-but-fast) adds edges randomly between 20 random points in the unit square, but with exponentially greater likelihood when close, according to the Euclidean metric.

```
edges = Function[{subsets}, 
   Pick[subsets, 
    UnitStep[
     RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length@subsets] - 
      Exp[- Dot[(subsets[[All, 1]] - subsets[[All, 2]])^2, {1., 
          1.}]]], 0]];
makegraphs[vert_] := 
  Graph[vert, UndirectedEdge @@@ edges[Subsets[vert, {2}], 1], 
   VertexCoordinates -> vert];
(*construct v as a list of packed arrays*)
ngraphs = 1;
randompoints = 
  Table[RandomReal[{-1/2, 1/2}, {20, 2}], {i, 1, ngraphs}];
graphs = makegraphs /@ randompoints; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000722, Null}

It simply generates a random geometric graph. With

```
graphs[[1]]
```

I get

[image]

I cannot see a simple way to get the connectivity to "wrap around", and give the graph on the surface of a "flat torus" i.e. the rectangle with periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: There is too much noise in your code. What does `PoissonDistribution` have to do with the question? Give us a [Minimal Working Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example).

Comment: Ok I will edit it, it is a portion of a longer code

Comment: Ok I added simpler code.

Comment: `IGGeometricGame` from IGraph/M does have a toroidal option, but otherwise you can't change the metric with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between your original post and this edit, it seems to me that you want to solve the following problem:

> Given a set of 2D points in a toroid `[0,w]x[0,h]`, compute a table of distances in an efficient way.

---

The following function assumes that `width` and `height` have been given some suitable values. It uses `Mod` to “wrap around”.

```
toroidalDelta[pointA_, pointB_] := 
  With[{delta = pointA - pointB}, {
    Min[Mod[{delta[[1]], -delta[[1]]}, width]], 
    Min[Mod[{delta[[2]], -delta[[2]]}, height]]
  }];
```

Let us check its action

```
width = 1; height = 2;
toroidalDelta[{0.1, 0.2}, {0.9, 1.8}]
(*{0.2, 0.4}*)
```

Note that the delta in the `x` direction wrapped around 1.0 while the delta in the `y` direction wrapped around 2.0 (as expected).

Let us check that the delta does not depend on the order of the points:

```
toroidalDelta[{0.9, 1.8}, {0.1, 0.2}]
(*{0.2, 0.4}*)
```

Once you have the delta, getting the norm is trivial:

```
toroidalNorm = Norm[toroidalDelta[##]] &;
```

From there, you can compute the probabilities with your favorite distribution. Using the function in your post:

```
prob = Exp[-toroidalNorm[##]] &;
prob[{0.9, 1.8}, {0.1, 0.2}]
(*0.639407*)
```

You might want to normalize the distribution. Also, take into acount (or not) the fact that `width != height`; but that is the subject for a different question.

Let us generate a list of random points in `[0,1]x[0,2]` and pick some random edges:

```
noPoints = 40; width = 1; height = 2;
points = Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, width}, {noPoints}], 
    RandomReal[{0, height}, {noPoints}]}];
edges = Reap[
    Table[If[prob[points[[i]], points[[j]]] > 0.6, 
      Sow[{points[[i]], points[[j]]}]], 
      {i, noPoints}, {j, i + 1, noPoints}]][[2, 1]];
```

Note that `Sow` is collecting the coordinates of the points instead of their indices because those points will be visualized using `Graphics3D`. You might want to change the sowing instruction to `Sow[{i,j}]` if you want to use those edges within a `Graph`. The visualization in 3D is important because it shows that the edges do not cross the holes.

```
from2DtoCyl[
   point_] := {(3 + Cos[(2 π)/width point[[1]]]) Sin[(2 π)/
      height point[[2]]], (3 + Cos[(2 π)/width point[[1]]]) Cos[(
      2 π)/height point[[2]]], Sin[(2 π)/width point[[1]]]};
Graphics3D[{PointSize[.03], Red, Point[from2DtoCyl /@ points], Black, 
  Line /@ Map[from2DtoCyl, edges, {2}], Opacity[0.05], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{(3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 
     Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}][[1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is ideal, thank you. Initially I saw it as building a random geometric graph with toroidal boundary conditions, but yes it is of course no more difficult than constructing toroidal distances on a rectangle.