# Depth limited search in mathematica

Tags: graphs-and-networks, algorithm

I often use

```
FindPath[G, 1, 2, {L}, All]
```

where $G$ is some graph. This finds all paths of length exactly $L$ edges  which run between nodes $1$ and $2$.

**In large graphs this is very slow.**

One solution is to (I think) use [Depth-Limited-Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-limited_search) starting at node $1$, of depth $L$.

I there an efficient way of doing this in Mathematica?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/finding-all-shortest-paths-between-two-vertices has helped (particularly Heike's answer)