# Locally randomizing a path on a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, random, algorithm

I have a walk $v_1 \ldots v_n$ on a graph $G$ and I want to apply the following operation to it: I wish to choose two indexes, $l$, $k$, and replace the sub-path from $v_l$ to $v_k$ with one of the shortest paths from $v_l$ to $v_k$, chosen uniformly at random among all such paths.

I would appreciate your assistance in implementing this in Mathematica!

I found a question related to mine (how to find all shortest paths) here: [Finding all shortest paths between two vertices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/finding-all-shortest-paths-between-two-vertices), but I am not sure how to utilize the answer there to select, uniformly at random, a path among all paths generated by the algorithm there.

Comment: I'm a Mathematica newbie, so I guess I am stuck "everywhere". In particular I have a problem generating all relevant shortest paths and choosing from them at random.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  To "replace" the sub-path means replacing vertexes and edges, but the sub-path already exists.  Draw by hand (if necessary) exactly what you're seeking.

Comment: I have a walk $v_1 \ldots v_i v_{i+1} \ldots v_j \ldots v_n$. I want to generate a new walk, $v_1 \ldots v_i u_{i+1} u_{i+2} \ldots u_{j-1} v_j \ldots v_n$, where $u_{i+1} \ldots u_{j-1}$ is the shortest path from $v_i$ to $v_j$, chosen uniformly at random among all such shortest paths.

Comment: I suggest to rewrite your question and focus on the main issue: How to find *all* shortest paths between two vertices?  Show an example graph with multiple shortest paths between the same two vertices (but something more complex than `CycleGraph[4]`)

Comment: Dear @Szabolcs, I don't think that is the main issue; you can find an algorithm for all shortest paths here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/finding-all-shortest-paths-between-two-vertices. The issue I am struggling with is *integration*, since I am not familiar withe Mathematica's syntax. I am not sure how to utilize the algorithm in e.g. the linked answer to randomly choose one of these paths! (In retrospect I will edit my post to include this helpful link.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this will be easier to follow.

This function finds all shortest paths in graph `g` between vertices `s` and `t`, and returns them in a list.

```
findAllShortestPaths[g_, s_, t_] := 
 FindPath[g, s, t, {GraphDistance[g, s, t]}, All]
```

This function takes a graph, a walk, and two indices into the `walk` array: `k` and `l`.  Then it replaces the section between the `k`th and `l`th elements of the walk, in the manner you described.

```
replacePath[g_, walk_, {k_, l_}] :=
 Join[
   Take[walk, k-1],
   RandomChoice@findAllShortestPaths[g, walk[[k]], walk[[l]] ],
   Take[walk, {l+1, -1}]
 ]
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[42];
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]

findAllShortestPaths[g, 1, 2]
(* {{1, 10, 2}, {1, 6, 2}} *)

walk = {7, 1, 10, 2};

HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[walk]]

replacePath[g, walk, {2, 4}]
(* {7, 1, 6, 2} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graph:

```
g = RandomGraph[{20, 50}];
```

Here is the path between $\nu_l = 5$ and $\nu_n = 9$ (chosen arbitrarily):

```
mypathlist = FindPath[g, 5, 9][[1]]
```

(* {5, 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 18, 10, 7, 9} *)

Here are two points along that path chosen arbitrarily:

```
myvertexes = RandomSample[mypathlist, 2]
```

(*
{2, 7}
*)

Here is the shortest path in $g$ between these vertexes:

```
mynewpathsegment = 
 FindShortestPath[g, myvertexes[[1]], myvertexes[[2]]]
```

(*
{2,7}
*)

If you want to get all such shortest paths:

```
myshortestlist = FindPath[gg, myvertexes[[1]], myvertexes[[2]], {GraphDistance[g, myvertexes[[1]], myvertexes[[2]]]}, All]
```

Then choose one of these shortest paths randomly:

```
myfinalshortpath = RandomChoice[myshortestlist]
```

Here is the original path with the new shortest path replacing the existing path segment:

```
mypathlist /. 
{x__, PatternSequence[myvertexes[[1]], __, myvertexes[[2]]], z__} -> 
{x, Sequence[myvertexes[[1]], myvertexes[[2]]], z}
```

(*
{5, 2, 7, 9}
*)

---

Note that this code automatically selects *one* of the shortest paths, if there are indeed multiple shortest paths.  You can verify this with this simple example:

```
gg = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 2 -> 4}]

FindShortestPath[gg, 1, 4]
```

(*
{1, 2, 4}
*)

(but not {1,3,4}).

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your help. Your answer *almost* achieves what I'm trying to do, but instead of "mynewpathsegment = 
 FindShortestPath[g, myvertexes[[1]], myvertexes[[2]]]", I want to generate a list of *all* shortest paths from $v_i$ and $v_j$, then choose *one* shortest path among those, at random .Do you have any idea how I might accomplish that?

Comment: @mich My code performs precisely what you seek.  Please see addendum to solution.

Comment: "Note that this code automatically and randomly selects one of the shortest paths,"  @David, it selects one of the shortest paths, *but not randomly*.  Each time you run this code on the same graph and same starting and ending vertices, it returns *the same* shortest path.    That is the problem the OP was referring to.  Identifying multiple shortest paths between the same points in important in many applications, e.g. in betweenness calculations.

Comment: mich and @Szabolcs:  OK.  Now fixed.